# How do I route traffic to a secondary site if first one is down?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-route53

I have my site hosted on an EC2 instance using nginx and I use Route 53 to route traffic to it.
Is it possible to have a setup where, if my EC2 instance is down for maintenance, I can have all traffic automatically routed to a different instance/server instead?

Where should I start looking/reading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can by setting up [DNS failover](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover-configuring.html) in Route53:

> You can configure Route 53 to check the health of those servers and to respond to DNS queries for example.com using only the servers that are currently healthy.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you, @Marcin!

Comment: @besi No problem. Glad could help.